# How may we prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sinh^2(x)-x\over \cosh^3(x)}\cdot{4x\over e^x}\mathrm dx=2-\zeta(2)?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given the integral

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sinh^2(x)-x\over \cosh^3(x)}\cdot{4x\over e^x}\mathrm dx=2-\zeta(2)\tag1$$

How may one prove $(1)?$

**An attempt:**

We may write $(1)$ as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sinh^2(x)-x\over \cosh(x)[1+\sinh^2(x)]}\cdot{4x\over e^x}\mathrm dx\tag2$$

No idea what substitution should use. Or rewrite as $(1)$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{4x\tanh^2(x)\over e^x\cosh(x)}\mathrm dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}{4x^2\over e^x\cosh^3(x)}\mathrm dx\tag3$$

Comment: Where do you get those integrals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite cumbersome but doable 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sinh^2(x)-x\over \cosh^3(x)}\cdot{4x\over e^x}\mathrm dx &=\int^\infty_0 \left\{\frac{2 e^x}{1 + e^{2 x}} + \frac{8 e^x (1 + x)}{(1 + e^{2 x})^3}- \frac{8 e^x (1 + x)}{(1 + e^{2 x})^2}\right\}{4x\over e^x}\mathrm dx
\\&=8\int^\infty_0\frac{x}{1 + e^{2 x}}\,dx+ 32\int^\infty_0\frac{x(1 + x)}{(1 + e^{2 x})^3}\,\mathrm dx-\frac{x(1 + x)}{(1 + e^{2 x})^2}\,dx
\\&=2\int^\infty_0\frac{x}{1 + e^{x}}\,\mathrm dx- 4\int^\infty_0\frac{e^x x (2 + x)}{(1 + e^x)^3}\,\mathrm dx
\\&=\zeta(2)-4\int^\infty_0\frac{e^x x (2 + x)}{(1 + e^x)^3}\,\mathrm dx
\\&=\zeta(2)-4\int^\infty_0\frac{1+x}{(1+e^x)^2}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\zeta(2)-2+4\int^\infty_0\frac{xe^{-x}}{1+e^x}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\zeta(2)-2+4\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int^\infty_0xe^{-(n+2)x}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\zeta(2)-2+4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+2)^2}\\
&=\zeta(2)-2+4-2\zeta(2)=\boxed{2-\zeta(2)}
\end{align}